# Slow Core-Data fetch operation, with readonly sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Core Data fetch operation is slow with a Read-only sqlite database. Can I improve its performance?

Background: I have a core-data model with 2 configurations. One for the default application store, and another for seed-data (SeedData.sqlite). The SeedData.sqlite is placed inside the application bundle, and is setup as a Read-only store. The SeedData.sqlite contains approximately 6500 records.

This is how I setup the persistent store:

```m
// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    // Attempt to load the persistent store
    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    // Create the default/ user model persistent store
    {
        NSString *storeFileName = [JTCoreDataManager defaultStoreName];
        NSString *configuration = @"AppName";
        NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationLocalDatabaseDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:storeFileName];

        // Define the Core Data version migration options
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                                 nil];

        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                       configuration:configuration
                                                                 URL:storeURL
                                                             options:options
                                                               error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    // Create the seed data persistent store
    {
        NSURL *seedDataURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SeedData" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
        NSString *configuration = @"SeedData";

        // Define the Core Data version migration options
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption,
                                 nil];

        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                       configuration:configuration
                                                                 URL:seedDataURL
                                                             options:options
                                                               error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]); abort();
            abort();
        }
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

The fetched results controller is setup like this:

```m
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Seed"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"magicOn == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                                           managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                                                                             sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                                      cacheName:nil];

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: What does the (slow) fetch request look like? Predicate, sort descriptors, ...

Comment: @MartinR Edited the question to include the information. It's just a simple/basic setup.

Comment: Did you create proper indexes on the seed data?

Comment: You are not opening the store with the option `NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption` set to YES, so it's not actually read-only. Additionally, the WAL sqlite pragma (which is currently the default) does not behave correctly with read only stores, pass `journal_mode` `DELETE` in your `NSSQLitePragmaOptions`.